# Replace CollectionViewCell with another CollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

A rather straightforward question - I have a collectionView with a couple of different cells, and I'd like to replace one of those cells with another cell.

Since func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell { is how I set my cells at the beginning, I don't suppose I can use another one of those. I have tried this

```
if indexPath.item == assignDotCell {
            return dotCell
        }
```

and then, when the action happen, I set assignDotCell to the indexnumber I want (it's initiated to 1000), and then tried

```
self.collectionView.assignDotCell = self.numberIWant

self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
                self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: [IndexPath (item: 5, section: self.activeRow)])
            }, completion: nil)
```

but of course that doesn't work. I would prefer to not call the entire cellForItemAt function again, since it would hide some of my other cells. Can it even be called?

Thankful for all leads!

EDIT: I had an error in how I assigned the cells inside the function! In case anyone else has the same problem, here's how it looks now.

```
public var updateCell = false

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

  let dotCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: dotID, for: indexPath) as! DotsCollectionViewCell

  if updateCell {
    for index in 0..<dotArray.count {
      if indexPath.item == dotArray[index] {
        return dotCell
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and to call it:

```
self.collectionView.updateCell = true
self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: [IndexPath (item: 5, section: self.activeRow)])
}, completion: nil)
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: It's not really clear what is wrong, reloadItems is indeed the proper way to do it, so maybe you have some unrelated issue with cellForItemAt indexPath or you are passing wrong indePath into reloadItems or something else. Could you provide a minimal example reproducing the issue?

Comment: @KonstantinOznobihin

The issue is, i already have a cellAtIndexPath function at in my CollectionView, which automatically gets called through the dataSource protocol. If I wanted to make another once, how can I make sure that the one that gets called automatically is the one I want called in the beginning, and how can I call a new one without calling the old one? It's very possible I'm wrong here, but as far as I can tell, I can't rename them. Thank you!

Comment: @Hyena - edit your post and show your full `cellForItemAt` func.

Comment: @Hyena you don't need multiple cellForItemAt functions, just change the one you have to return different cells depending on the state of your view controller

Comment: @KonstantinOznobihin As it turns out, I had an error in how I assigned the the cells in the cellForItemAt function, and the re-assignment was correct, if a bit ugly. But I would not have thought to look into that if not for your answer, thank you so much!